# Showing that a sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Assume $x_n^k, x_n$ to be real for all $k$ and for all $n$. Suppose that I have $x_k^{(n)}\to x_k$ as $n\to \infty$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$. Then can something be said about $\sup_k|x_k^{(n)}-x_k|$?

Given any $\epsilon>0$, $(\forall k\in \mathbb N) \exists N_k\in \mathbb N, n\ge N_k\implies |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|<\epsilon/2$.

I can't do $\sup_k$ on  both sides as that would change $N_k$ as well.

Is there any way by which I can conclude that the supremum is $0$ for large $n$?

While trying to prove this, I observed the following inequality: $\sup\{|x_n|: n\in \mathbb N\}\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_n|$. (Proof: If RHS is infinite then there is nothing to prove so suppose RHS to be $<\infty$. For every $n$, $|x_n|\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_n|$, whence the result follows. QED)

Fixing an $\epsilon>0$, for every $k\in \mathbb N$, there exists $N_k\in \mathbb N$ such that $k\ge N_k\implies |x_k^{(n)}-x_k|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}$.

Using the inequality shown above, I'm tempted to do the following:

$\sup_k|x_k^{(n)}-x_k|\le \epsilon \sum_k\frac 1{2^{k+1}}<\epsilon.$, whence I get that $\|(x_k^{(n)})-(x_k)\|_\infty\to 0.$

But it seems wrong as $N_k$'s are varying. Is there any way to get the conclusion?

Comment: You need additional assumptions as you require the so called uniform convergence of a family of infinitely many sequences. In general nothing can be said. For example let $x_k^{(n)}={k\over n}.$ Then every sequence tends to $0,$ but $\sup_k x_k^{(n)}=\infty.$ Do you have a special family in mind ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks a lot for the comment. The question in OP came up while doing an another exercise: It is also given that: $(z_n)$, where $z_n=(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in the sense that: given any $\epsilon>0,$ there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $m,n \ge N$, $\sup_k|x_k^{(m)}- x_k^{(n)}|\lt \epsilon$. But still I have the same question. Is there any way now to show the conclusion that I seek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to prove that $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is a complete metric space. That is, given a Cauchy sequence $z_n\in\ell^\infty$, you want to show that $z_n$ converges to an element $z\in\ell^\infty$. The candidate for $z$ is the sequence whose coordinates are the pointwise limits of the coordinates of $z_n$:
$$
z := (\lim_{n}x_1^{(n)},\lim_nx_2^{(n)},\dots).
$$
The first thing to show is that $z$ is actually a bounded sequence; I leave it to you.

Now you'd like to show that
$$
\sup_k|x^{(n)}_k-x_k|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.
$$

For a general infinite collection of convergent sequences $\{(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^\infty\}_n$, say with $x_k^{(n)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x_k$, nothing like this can be said because of examples like $x_k^{(n)} = k/n$. However, in our situation, we also are given that the sequence $z_n$ is Cauchy. So, let $\epsilon > 0$ and find $N$ so that if $n,m\ge N$, we have
$$
\sup_k|x_k^{(n)}-x_k^{(m)}|\le\epsilon.
$$
Fix $k$ then and let $m\to\infty$ in the inequality $|x_k^{(n)}-x_k^{(m)}|\le\epsilon$ to find
$$
|x_k^{(n)}-x_k|\le\epsilon.
$$
The important point now is that this last inequality holds for *any* fixed $k$, so we conclude that if $n\ge N$,
$$
\sup_k|x_k^{(n)}-x_k|\le\epsilon.
$$
Together with your own proof that $z$ is actually a bounded sequence, this finishes the proof that $\ell^\infty$ is complete.

Comment: $(x_k^{(n)})\in l_\infty$ so let $p_n=\sup|x_k^{(n)}|$.For every $i\in \mathbb N$,  $|z_i|\le |z_i-z_i^{(N)}|+|z_i^{(N)}|\le \epsilon+ p_n\implies \sup |z_i|<\infty\implies z\in l_\infty$. Thanks a lot :-).